# Prevent application from throwing webrequest timeout error inside application and catch it

Tags: vb.net, timeout, httpwebrequest

I'm working on handling timeout errors etc. in a httpwebrequest, but it keeps throwing the errors in the debugging, which means I can't show the Statuscode in my application.. I have tried to use Try catch, but when I try to grab the postresponse statuscode. The only thing I can get from the catch is the description of the error I see in the debugging, not the status code of the response..

Update: ( I ended up doing this.. I still can't get the different statuscodes, but this will do I guess)

```
Try
                postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

                Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
                data = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

                'Get title

                Dim reg = New Regex("<title>(.*?)</title>")
                Dim matches = reg.Matches(data)
                Dim wtitle As String = "No title"
                For Each mat As Match In matches
                    wtitle = mat.Value.Replace("<title>", "").Replace("</title>", "")
                Next mat

                ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(3).Text = wtitle

                'OK
                ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(1).Text = "OK"

            Catch ex As Exception When WebExceptionStatus.Timeout
                ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(1).Text = "Timeout"
            Catch ox As Exception When WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure
                MsgBox("Name resolution failure")
            End Try
```

Original:

```
Dim data As String = Nothing

            Try
                Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
                postreq.Method = "GET"
                postreq.KeepAlive = True
                postreq.Timeout = 5000 '10s
                postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
                postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                postreq.Referer = "https://www.facebook.com"
                Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
                postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

                If postresponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then

                    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
                    data = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

                    'Get title

                    Dim reg = New Regex("<title>(.*?)</title>")
                    Dim matches = reg.Matches(data)
                    Dim wtitle As String = "No title"
                    For Each mat As Match In matches
                        wtitle = mat.Value.Replace("<title>", "").Replace("</title>", "")
                    Next mat

                    ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(3).Text = wtitle

                    'OK
                    ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(1).Text = "OK"

                Else

                    ListView1.Items(ci).SubItems(1).Text = "Fejl"

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Answer (score 3):

The `ex` exception object is of generic `Exception` type, which does not provide any HttpWebRequest specific information. Add a catch block for a `WebException` object:

```
Try
    ' ..........
Catch ex As WebException
    If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.Timeout Then
        MsgBox("The request has timed out!")
    Else
        MsgBox(ex.Status)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually ended up doing something similar. I have updated my question. Thanks though. I still can't get the status code though, but I guess this will do.